# jQuery Slide Menu in Master Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have a ASP.NET custom server control menu with the following jQuery in the head of the master page. The problem is that when I have a button on a regular form it causes the slide action in the side menu in the master page to activate every time it is clicked in the form... how can I prevent this so that the slide action only happens on initial page load or when a different men item is clicked?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Expand/Collapse All
    $('#example1 .expand_all').click(function() {
        $('#menu1 > li > a.collapsed').addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').parent().find('> ul').slideDown('medium');
    });
    $('#example1 .collapse_all').click(function() {
        $('#menu1 > li > a.expanded').addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').parent().find('> ul').slideUp('medium');
    });
    // Slide
    $("#menu1 > li > a.expanded + ul").slideToggle("medium");
    $("#menu1 > li > a").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded").toggleClass("collapsed").parent().find('> ul').slideToggle("medium");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `.one()`? Maybe this will help: [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Edit:
I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="isloaded" runat="server" Value="false" EnableViewState="true" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    var isLoaded = document.getElementById("isloaded").value;
    if (isLoaded == "false") {
        //your code
        document.getElementById("isloaded").value = "true";
    }
});
```

Comment: Adding it to the SlideToggle methods prevented to slide from working at all: $('#menu1 > li > a.expanded + ul').one.slideToggle('medium');

Comment: I meant using it like this: $(document).ready(function () { /*do something*/}).one()
If this doesn't work, you could try using a hidden field to save the  state of your menu(something like isLoaded). If the menu is already loaded, then don't do the animation.

Comment: Okay I tried it... but menu slider still activating when a simple form button is clicked...

Comment: If I used a hidden field, could you give the syntax for checking an IsLoaded boolean in jQuery?

Comment: Not getting a value property for document.getElementById("isloaded") - only seeing a nodeValue property and that isn't working... (null)

Comment: "document.getElementById" needs the ClientID of your control. Make sure that your HiddenField is placed in your MasterPage. Otherwise, ASP appends a prefix to the client id :)

Comment: It's in master page - moved script below form closing tag and hidden field inside opening form tag - it's rendering as: <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$isLoaded" id="isLoaded" value="true" />

Comment: @IrishChieftain let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1226/discussion-between-mario-tco-and-irishchieftain)